# Div visible in headed Chrome, invisible in headless Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, google-chrome-headless, katalon-studio

I am trying to test a login page of our software in Katalon Studio (it uses Selenium), and headless Chrome doesn't render an iframe that the welcome message is shown in. `WebUI.verifyElementVisible` fails while `WebUI.verifyElementPresent` succeeds. The screenshot doesn't show it either. Headed Chrome runs the test without hiccups.

When I run Chrome from command line in headless mode, its `--dump-dom` option produces a truncated output, but I can see that the div container for the iframe is invisible:

```
<div id="Div_AlertWin" style="position:absolute;display:none" onclose="fnLoginUnloadAlert()">
```

When I check it in the headed Chrome, it's visible,

```
<div id="Div_AlertWin" style="position: absolute; display: block; left: 183.5px; top: 218.5px;" onclose="fnLoginUnloadAlert()">
```

**It looks like one of the startup JS scripts that shows the div doesn't run correctly in the headless Chrome. How can I debug its JS execution?** I cannot use `--remote-debugging-port`, because appspot is blocked by the company firewall.

Answer (score 0):

As per the HTML you have provided, the `Normal Chrome Browser` renders the `HTML DOM` as follows :

```
<div id="Div_AlertWin" style="position: absolute; display: block; left: 183.5px; top: 218.5px;" onclose="fnLoginUnloadAlert()">
```

Where as the `Headless Chrome Browser` renders the `HTML DOM` as follows :

```
<div id="Div_AlertWin" style="position:absolute;display:none" onclose="fnLoginUnloadAlert()">
```

So here we need to change to `style="position:absolute;display:block"` and them find/locate/search the `WebElement` as follows:

```
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("document.getElementById('Div_AlertWin').style.display='block';");
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("Div_AlertWin"));
```

Comment: But why does it do that? There's a JS script that changes the style of the element that is triggered by `onload`, how can I find out why it doesn't run correctly in headless?

Comment: @Alexey If you can confirm me that the solution works for you I can explain about the solution I offered and how it works.

Comment: I cannot test it until the 13th. I'll get back to you then.

Comment: @Alexey Did you test this?

Comment: I switched to a newer version of Katalon that has headless Firefox, no error occurs in it.